# Typescript no longer recognising custom classes and interfaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, asp.net-core, ecmascript-5

For some reason my angularJS controller no longer recognises my custom types, I have given all the files full write permissions.

I dont have a tsconfig.json file, I am using visual studio 2019 which supports TS out of the box. These are the project settings..

[image]

This is my project structure in .net core

[image]

This is the class which looks fine.. which is in the Classes folder.

[image]

But the controller complains it cant see the type..

[image]

This worked fine before, so I wonder if checking in and out of TFS caused an issue, but all files have full write access now. :(

This is the specific error..

[image]

Comment: I have noticed there are no sourcemap *.d.ts files for the classes etc.. surely these are supposed to autogenerate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by adding the ts files with the add new file extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.AddNewFile

When you add a ts file with shift+F2 you dont get the corresponding *.js and *.d.ts files which are auto generated.

The content type on the file was not Typescript, it was set to resource.